# What does gpu_mem_get_free_no_cache() actually do? [Fastai]

Tags: python, deep-learning, fast-ai

I was training the Language model as shown in Lesson 4 of Part 1 of the Fastai Course. At first, after training the frozen model, when I went to finetune it by unfreezing it and started training, I got an error related to **Insufficient GPU Memory available**.

At this stage, I ran `gpu_mem_get_free_no_cache()`, which freed up about **6GB** of **VRAM**. I then loaded my saved model, and the finetuning stage ran perfectly. I thought that `gpu_mem_get_free_no_cache()` removed my model from the memory, and hence after loading the saved model, I was able to train properly.

```
learning_rate = slice(1e-1/5)
learn_lm.fit_one_cycle(1, max_lr = learning_rate, moms = (0.8,0.7))

learn_lm.save("lm_freezed")

gpu_mem_get_free_no_cache()

learn_lm.load("lm_freezed");

learn_lm.unfreeze()
learn_lm.lr_find()
learn_lm.recorder.plot()

learning_rate = slice(1e-5/1e-3)
learn_lm.fit_one_cycle(1, max_lr = learning_rate, moms = (0.8,0.7))
```

After completing my finetuning, I decided to predict on a user-input text. I ran `gpu_mem_get_free_no_cache()` which again freed up about **5.5GB** of **VRAM**. I hoped that trying to predict on a user-text wouldn't work since the model was cleared by the `gpu_mem_get_free_no_cache()` code. However, `learn_lm.predict(text, words_per_sentence, temperature = 0.5)` worked perfectly, even though my VRAM usage was fixed to 2.7GB (while finetuning, the VRAM usage was constant at 7.4GB). So, what does `gpu_mem_get_free_no_cache()` actually do/clear? Does it free up the space required by the gradients and optimizer states, since it seems the weights aren't cleared else the model wouldn't have been able to perform inference?

```
text = "This is a fine "
words_per_sentence = 50
n_sentences = 4

learn_lm.predict(text, words_per_sentence, temperature = 0.5)
```